# iPhone PayPal Payments

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

I'm currently making an iPhone app that allows users to post items for sell that other users can purchase. I would like for them to be able to pay each other through the application using PayPal, but I'm not sure if this is currently allowed under Apple's app submission policy.

Also, if it is allowed, I need to know how I would go about setting up PayPal to work within the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and safest way is to navigate to a webview with the paypal login URL

[This](http://namu6.com/766/) might help you
You could generate a link for each product and if the other client wants to buy it, he gets this link from the server/db